# Does Ember CLI support IE11 or IE10?

Tags: ember.js, internet-explorer-11, ember-cli, internet-explorer-10

We have an ember cli based site and works fine in all browsers except for IE11 & IE10.

The site loads in IE11 / IE10 too but after viewing few pages it just crashes without any error in console or logs.

Our application is making cross domain requests to fetch/save data. Not sure if that's the problem or if there is a limit to number of requests/data that IE11 allows ?

Also not sure if Ember cli build sites work in IE11/IE10 flawlessly as stumbled across this article while looking up for my problem.

https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/301

Any help is appreciated as to why the site loads but crashes after viewing some pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an issue with a `production` build or just when running with `ember serve`?

Comment: issue with ember serve & build both. basically able to access the site & view few pages before it crashes.

Comment: i was hoping to find an answer here, facing the same problem in IE10

Answer (score 1):

Behind the scenes Ember uses [Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel) to transpile ES6 to vanilla JavaScript. Babel does not support Internet Explorer <= 10:

https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/doc/design/compiler-environment-support.md

It actually goes as far to say:

> NOTE: If Babel works in any of the unsupported environments, it is purely coincidental and has no bearing on future compatibility. Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

Ember does support IE11 but an IE11 compatible version is only built in production by default. So if you are trying to do development or testing in IE11, you're going to need to modify your configuration.

At the bare-minimum, you're going to need to include ie11 in your browsers config of your `target.js`

'use strict';

```
const browsers = [
  'last 1 Chrome versions',
  'last 1 Firefox versions',
  'last 1 Safari versions',
  'ie 11'                    // INCLUDE THIS LINE
];

module.exports = {
  browsers
};
```

That step is mandatory. This next step is optional but I recommend it if you're project is using any 3rd party libraries. As further step, you may run into additional console errors (due to ember addons) if you do not enable all polyfills in your `ember-cli-build.js`

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    'ember-cli-babel': {
      includePolyfill: true
    }
  });

  return app.toTree();
};
```